# My gitlab-ce fall with ssl error, how I can resolve?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, gitlab-ce

I have ran gitlab-ce into docker and I want to up it on https
On the host I nginx with reverse proxy, because I forward ports into wan from lan
my nginx conf looks that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gitlab.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/dir/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/dir/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

my compose.yml

```
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab/giltab_home/config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./gitlab/giltab_home/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./gitlab/giltab_home/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    env_file:
      - .env
```

my .env for gitlab

```
GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASS
GITLAB_HTTPS=True
GITLAB_SSL_CERTIFICATE=/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt
GITLAB_SSL_KEY=/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.com.key
```

my gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.mydomain.com'
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.com.key"
```

error what I met

```
vs@dv1:/t/k/a/y$ sudo docker compose exec gitlab gitlab-ctl reconfigure
Running handlers complete
[2023-08-29T21:22:57+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Infra Phase failed. 2 resources updated in 23 seconds
[2023-08-29T21:22:57+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cinc-stacktrace.out
[2023-08-29T21:22:57+00:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-08-29T21:22:57+00:00] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace.out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT
[2023-08-29T21:22:57+00:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-08-29T21:22:57+00:00] FATAL: RuntimeError: letsencrypt_certificate[gitlab.mydomain.com] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 6) had an error: RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 43) had an error: RuntimeError: ruby_block[create certificate for gitlab.mydomain.com] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 110) had an error: RuntimeError: [gitlab.mydomain.com] Validation failed, unable to request certificate, Errors: [{url: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/7994711214/JUOaBA, status: invalid, error: {"type"=>"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection", "detail"=>"83.221.215.74: Fetching https://gitlab.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/rcDu-f036j7Y0vQYikbY-B_dyD-fv01w: Connection refused", "status"=>400}} ]
```